# log4j file is not getting created on ubuntu operating system

Tags: java, ubuntu

this is question  regarding Ubuntu OS , I have an Java application 
properly working on windows as well as also working on Ubuntu OS , but here in Ubuntu OS the path is not getting set properly in 'Log4j.xml' file .
   ' ' , what is correct value of path  for Ubuntu OS  .

Comment: The path is the same for any operating system. Note: Linux is case sensitive so make sure you use lower case only.

Comment: Showing us your log4j.xml might help us find the issue for you

Comment: Remember to use / instead of \\ for your path

Comment: ['
      <param name="file" value="/home/administrator/zealWayMAP.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" 
   value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
 </appender>

 <root>
  <level value="debug" />
  <appender-ref ref="file" />
 </root>

</log4j:configuration>']

Answer (score 0):

Filenames on Windows and OS X are case insensitive whereas they are case sensitive on Linux.

If your log configuration file is really called ***L***og4j.xml it won't be detected on Linux since Log4J is looking for ***l***og4j.xml, try renaming the file so it's lower case only.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but  my file name is lower case log4j.xml .